# Programmatically check if IPv6 is enabled on windows

Tags: c++, windows, ipv6

Is there a way to programmatically check if IPv6 is installed/enabled on windows using c++? Either at an interface level, or system wide.

Comment: Just because it's enabled on the host, doesn't mean the router will support it...

Comment: I need to provide the user with some extra configuration options if their machine supports IPv6. Many of my users are running on older machines without IPv6 support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`WSCEnumProtocols()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742237(VS.85).aspx) can be used to check whether IPv6 is installed as a protocol.

Answer (score 4):

With a lot of network availability things the easiest way is to attempt to use it and catch the exceptions if it fails.

Answer (score 1):

One answer would be to enumerate the system interfaces using `GetAdapterAddresses()` and look for an IPv6 address.

Answer (score 0):

Remember, on XP it is necessary to run `ipv6 install` before IPv6 will be available, so it's a little bit more complicated than you might think.

Answer (score -1):

Easiest is just to try opening a socket,

```
const int sock6 = socket (AF_INET6, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
const BOOL is_ip6_enabled = (SOCKET_ERROR != sock6);
close (sock6);
```

Comment: This doesn't really work. In windows 2008 you still get a socket handle even if IPv6 is not enabled.

Comment: You might be confusing "enabled" with "having an IPv6 interface"?